# Is there an official Java API to parse HTML?

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

I have an HTML files in which I need to add some attributes to HTML tags using Java, but for some (stupid) reason I can't use a third-party libraries, so the question is, is there an official Java API to parse HTML files? if not, what other options do I have? I'm thinking in adding the attributes without paring the files but I'm guessing that may cause problems later.

Comment: Does it have to _parse_ the HTML? Can't you do any string processing?

Comment: *is there an official Java API to parse HTML files?* No. *if not, what other options do I have?* Write one.

Comment: I can, all I want to do is to given an HTML tag I need to add an attribute to that tag without messing up the format of the document, I tried an XML parser but HTML is not always well formed and it was causing errors when tags are not properly closed.